# Annotation has apiVersion v1beta1

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks, kubernetes-rbac

I am planning to upgrade Kubernetes clusters from 1.21 to 1.22. I was going through the release notes and noticed `ClusterRole`, `RoleBinding` and `ClusterRoleBinding` should use rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1 as rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1 is being deprecated.

Here is the output from one of my resource `rolebinding/test-rw`. `apiversion` says `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1` but in annotations, it says `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1`. Why does annotation have `v1beta1` version? is it because it was initially deployed with `v1beta` version and later on updated to `v1` version?

```
$ kubectl get RoleBinding/test-rw -o yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1beta1","kind":"RoleBinding","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"test-rw","namespace":"default"},"roleRef":{"apiGroup":"","kind":"ClusterRole","name":"admin"},"subjects":[{"apiGroup":"","kind":"Group","name":"test-rw"}]}
  creationTimestamp: "2017-08-18T11:40:22Z"
  name: test-rw
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "214"
  uid: f8a89do8-885f-11e9-8dd8-12afbb11be0c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `kubectl api-versions` to check the available API versions.

or `kubectl explain pod` to check the version

In Annotation, it's last applied config but what you are seeing is API server preferred API version.

Kubectl is the client and it will show the **API server** preferred version or whatever you request for using that.

```
kubectl get RoleBinding.v1beta1 test-rw -o yaml
```

So API version while creating Rolebilding not get affected when you are trying to get using **kubectl**.